# L'Hôpital's as $x$ tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, logarithms, infinity

I'm searching for the explanation to the limit of:

$$
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x\, \ln\frac{x+1}{x-1}.
$$

I know the answer is 2, but I can't seem to get there.
The problem is in my textbook under a section with l'Hôpital.

Comment: Many people here have taken time out of their lives to answer your question. If one of them has helped you, please select it as the answer.

Comment: @GabrielH Kind of user is also bothering me, so right now I'm becoming selective to answer of problems here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $$\ln \frac{x+1}{x-1} = \ln(x+1) - \ln(x-1)$$ so that $$x \cdot \ln \frac{x+1}{x-1}$$ can be rewritten as $$\frac{\ln(x+1) - \ln(x-1)}{x^{-1}}.$$ Now,

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} x \ln \frac{x+1}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x-1}}{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$$

Find a common denominator for the two terms in the numerator, cancel fractions, and you will arrive at the desired answer of 2.

Note: Indeed, $\ln \frac{x+1}{x-1} \rightarrow 0$ and $ x^{-1} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. Therefore, we have the required form $0/0$ and L'Hopital's rule is applicable.

Comment: I would say - for limit of type $\frac{\infty-\infty}{0}$ You can not use l'Hospital rule.

Comment: I do not think he would. L'Hospital would apply when the ln's are combined (zero over zero). In his last step, taking a derivative of that NUM would be so much easier because of seperate ln terms... He should have mentioned that though.

Comment: Yes but $\ln \frac{x+1}{x-1} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ and splitting the logarithm does not change this.

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: So I would say it is O.K.

Comment: From a pedagogical standpoint, this is probably the approach one would teach a calc 1 student to approach problems like this

Comment: The order of presentation could be a bit confusing.  The first "hint" has nothing to do with how to see the problem as an application of l'Hopital's rule; it's a shortcut in finding the derivative of the numerator when actually applying the rule.

Comment: I will work on it for next time, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need L'Hospital to solve it. You can write your limit as

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^x=\ln \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^x.$$

Now,

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^x$$

is an indetermination $1^{\infty}.$ This can be solved as

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^x=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}-1\right)x}.$$

Anyway, if you want to apply L'Hospital you can express your limit as

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln\frac{x+1}{x-1}}{\frac{1}{x}}$$ to get an indetermination $\frac{0}{0}.$ Now you can apply L'Hospital. That is,

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln\frac{x+1}{x-1}}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{x-1}{x+1} \frac{-2}{(x-1)^2}}{\frac{-1}{x^2}}=\cdots =2.$$

Comment: The passage where the logarithm disappears should be justified: you are stating that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)^{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{(f(x)-1)g(x)}$, which is not immediate.

Comment: Just in case of an indetermination $1^{\infty}.$ It follows form the definition of $e.$

Comment: *I* know it, the OP probably doesn't.

Comment: You are right. I don't know if the OP knows it or not. I have assumed this formula was known before the use of L'Hospital rule, because it doesn't make use of derivatives. In my country or, at least, in my region, is the way it is done.

Comment: I suggest to add a note about it.

Answer (score 2):

Way 1.
$$
x \ln\frac{x+1}{x-1}=x\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{x-1}\right)=x\left(\frac{2}{x-1}+\mathcal O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)=\frac{2}{x-1}+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\to 2.
$$

We have used the fact that
$$
\ln (1+w)=w+{\mathcal O}(w^2),
$$
for $w$ small.

Way 2. Otherwise, set $h=1/x$, and now $h\to 0$, and our linear becomes
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1+h}{1-h}\right)}{h},
$$
but this is simply equal to $f'(0)$ where
$$
f(x)=\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)
$$
and clearly
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{1-x},
$$
and thus $f'(0)=2$.

Comment: I presume that the typical introductory calculus class would not have went over this method, but nice and short altogether.

Comment: See a second method in the edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can observe that
$$
\frac{x+1}{x-1}=\frac{x-1+2}{x-1}=1+\frac{2}{x-1}
$$
Now write $x=(x-1)+1$ and transform your limit in
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left((x-1)\log\left(1+\frac{2}{x-1}\right)+
  \log\left(1+\frac{2}{x-1}\right)\right)
$$
The second summand has limit $0$, so it can be removed and you can do the substitution $1/t=x-1$ that brings the limit into
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log(1+2t)}{t}
$$
that's the derivative of $f(t)=\log(1+2t)$ at $0$; since
$$
f'(t)=\frac{2}{1+2t}
$$
we have $f'(0)=2$ as in your solution sheet.

For another method, more direct, observe that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\log\frac{x+1}{x-1}=0
$$
(and that $(x+1)/(x-1)>0$ for $x>1$), so your limit is in the form $\infty\cdot0$. Such a form becomes either $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ by “reversing” one of the factors. More precisely, if $\lim_{x\to?}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to?}g(x)=0$, you can consider either
$$
f(x)g(x)=\frac{g(x)}{1/f(x)}
$$
which takes the $0/0$ form, or
$$
f(x)g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{1/g(x)}
$$
which is in the form $\infty/\infty$. We can apply l'Hôpital's theorem to both forms. I used ? to mean any point (finite or infinite) at which the limit is taken.

Doing $1/\log(\dots)$ is a last resource, because the derivative won't lose the logarithm; on the other hand, the derivative of the logarithm loses it, while the derivative of $1/x$ is “easy”, so the first strategy to try is with the $0/0$ form above:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log\frac{x+1}{x-1}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log\frac{x+1}{x-1}}{1/x}
$$
Now the derivative of the numerator $\log\frac{x+1}{x-1}=\log(x+1)-\log(x-1)$ is
$$
\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x-1}=\frac{(x-1)-(x+1)}{x^2-1}=-\frac{2}{x^2-1}
$$
and the derivative of the denominator $1/x$ is $-1/x^2$, so we have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log\frac{x+1}{x-1}}{1/x}
\overset{\mathrm{(H)}}{=}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-2/(x^2-1)}{-1/x^2}\overset{*}{=}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^2}{x^2-1}=2
$$
An equality is marked with (H) to show the application of l'Hôpital's theorem; the one marked with $*$ shows that it's very important to simplify the formula before attempting again with the big theorem.

Comment: You have a typo. When you write $\frac{x+1}{x-1}\to 0$ you have omitted $\ln.$

Comment: @mfl Thanks for noting!

Answer (score 1):

Using the expression in mfl's answer (using continuity of the logarithmic function):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log\frac{x+1}{x-1}=\log\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac2{x-1}\right)^x$$

But

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac2{x-1}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac2{x-1}\right)^{x-1}\left(1+\frac2{x-1}\right)= e^2\cdot1=e^2$$

and thus the wanted limit is

$$\log e^2=2$$